# jQuery UI external tabs plugin issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, flexigrid

After I link an external html - which is a flexigrid table - all the flexigrid formatting and functions become extremely buggy. Has any one had this issue before or have any advice?

This is what I am doing to link the external html document:

```
 <div id = "tabs">

 <li><a href="#paymentsTab">Transaction History</a></li><

 <div id = "paymentsTab"></div>

 </div>

 </div>

<script>

    $(function() {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
            $('#paymentsTab').load('financialTransactions.html');
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Your html markup is a mess: a <li> must be in a <ul>. There's a <.

Comment: @wumm, it is like that. when i put the <ul> in it actually marked-up this page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to solve it:

```
         $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                            ui.ajaxSettings.dataTypes[0] = "html"; //very important!
                            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                                    ui.panel.html(
                                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                            });
                    }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not neassary 
Do it so:

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="financialTransactions.html">Transaction History</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Look at the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax). This examples does the same what you like to do.

Comment: jQuery tabs doesn't do external links like that, I tried it and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#tabs').tabs();
            $('#paymentsTab').load('financialTransactions.html');
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt change anything :(